# While trying to upgrade postgresql postgresql-10 I get libpq5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.26 is to be installed

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I've been trying to upgrade postgresql in my Ubuntu machine from 9.3 to 10.
When I try

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-10`

I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-10 : Depends: postgresql-client-10 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: postgresql-common (>= 182~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.3~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
```

Then subsequently when I try

`sudo apt-get install libpq5`

I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.26 is to be installed
```

One answer on the internet suggest I install the specific version, so I tried

`sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1`

but I got

```
E: Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1' for 'libssl1.0.0' was not found
```

I have tried a lot of answers given on the internet but to no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason it was not installing was because it was somehow trying to install versions which were not compatible with ubuntu 14.04 so I took the installed versions from a colleague and it worked.
The versions to install 

`libpq5:amd64 11.0-1.pgdg14.04+2
postgresql-client-common 195.pgdg14.04+1
postgresql-client-10 10.5-2.pgdg14.04+1
postgresql-10 10.5-2.pgdg14.04+1`